# Сборка приложения в Android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

При попытке сборки приложения в Android studio получаю ошибку https://gist.github.com/6607320/3e38d67b75d2a6278dfaced809e651fb

> Information:05.06.2019 21:53 - Compilation completed with 1 error and
>   0 warnings in 11 s 945 ms Error:Internal error:
>   (java.lang.ClassNotFoundException)
>   com.google.wireless.android.sdk.stats.IntellijIndexingStats$Index
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   com.google.wireless.android.sdk.stats.IntellijIndexingStats$Index     at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)    at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)     at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)     at
>   com.intellij.util.indexing.counters.IndexCounters.(IndexCounters.java:34)
>     at
>   com.intellij.util.indexing.impl.MapReduceIndex.(MapReduceIndex.java:86)
>     at
>   org.jetbrains.jps.backwardRefs.index.CompilerReferenceIndex$CompilerMapReduceIndex.(CompilerReferenceIndex.java:214)
>     at
>   org.jetbrains.jps.backwardRefs.index.CompilerReferenceIndex.(CompilerReferenceIndex.java:73)
>     at
>   org.jetbrains.jps.backwardRefs.JavaCompilerBackwardReferenceIndex.(JavaCompilerBackwardReferenceIndex.java:12)
>     at
>   org.jetbrains.jps.backwardRefs.JavaBackwardReferenceIndexWriter.initialize(JavaBackwardReferenceIndexWriter.java:74)
>     at
>   org.jetbrains.jps.backwardRefs.JavaBackwardReferenceIndexBuilder.buildStarted(JavaBackwardReferenceIndexBuilder.java:40)
>     at
>   org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.runBuild(IncProjectBuilder.java:358)
>     at
>   org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.build(IncProjectBuilder.java:178)
>     at
>   org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildRunner.runBuild(BuildRunner.java:138)
>     at
>   org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildSession.runBuild(BuildSession.java:302)
>     at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildSession.run(BuildSession.java:135)
>     at
>   org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildMain$MyMessageHandler.lambda$channelRead0$0(BuildMain.java:229)
>     at
>   org.jetbrains.jps.service.impl.SharedThreadPoolImpl.lambda$executeOnPooledThread$0(SharedThreadPoolImpl.java:42)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Comment: Не надо ссылку, поместить лог прямо в вопрос текстом. Также добавьте подробностей по приложению. Ошибка у вас очень специфическая. Возможно вы как-то не так проект создали. Попробуйте создать новый с дефолтными значениями и аккуратно выбрать целевую платформу. Возможно вы выбрали умные часы случайно и оно не работает или либ каких-то нет.

Comment: Версия AS? Была похожая проблема с плагином Findbugs, отключите если он есть у вам.

Comment: Приложение работает на Android 6 и выше, в приложение использую API карты OSM.
Версия Android studio 3.4.1, плагин Findbugs в Android studio не установил.